# flash message when user logout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, devise

In devise.en.yml,i kept signed_out message empty as

> ```
> sessions:
>
>   signed_out: ""
> ```

i am having a condition where if failed attempt > 3 then we have to make user signed out.
For this i wrote in the controller as:

> if params[:failed_attempt].to_i > 3
>
> ```
>     current_user.update_attribute(:status, false)
>
>      redirect_to destroy_user_session_path(@user), :notice =>
> ```
>
> "locked"
>             end

I am able to update attribute and able to logout but **couldnot able to display notice or flash message.** Please try to help me out.
I am getting all the messages except this. I also tried :

> redirect_to destroy_user_session_path(@user)
>
> flash[:notice] = "locked"

But no use.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are setting the flash variable but not actually rendering out the content... try this:

In your application.html.erb before the `<%= yield %>` paste in code like this:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <div data-alert id="flashes" class="alert-box  <%= name %>">
        <%= content_tag :div, msg, id: "flash_#{name}" %>
        <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

You can style it afterwards whatever way you want

Answer (score -2):

This done the trick. I just changed my signout as:

> ```
>     sign_out(current_user), :notice =>"locked"
> ```

instead of

> ```
>  redirect_to destroy_user_session_path(@user), :notice => "locked"
> ```